# 10,000,000 Integer Array Insertion Sort in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion

So I have written the insertion sort code properly to where it will successfully create arrays of 10, 1,000, 100,000 and 1,000,000 integers between 1,000 and 9,999 and complete the insertion sort algorithm just fine. However, when I attempt the last step of 10,000,000 integers, the array is created, but the code never fully completes. I have allowed it plenty of time to complete, upwards of 4 or 5 hours, to no avail. Anybody have any ideas of what the issue may be here? Is the executer having issues comprehending that many integers or what could the issue stem from? I have included a copy of the insertion algorithm that I have written.

```
    public static void insertion(int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int j = i -1;
        int temp = a[i];

        while(j > 0 && temp < a[j]) {
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `j > 0` with `j >= 0`

Comment: I guess 5 hours is not enough

Comment: It may be simply due to the significant difference between 1 million and 10 million. How quickly can you simply traverse through the an array (no while loop) of 1 million elements vs 10 million?

Comment: i wonder why you have to use Insertion sort instead other sort "Merge sort and Quick sort". If only for testing the insertion sort, i think 1000 or 10.000 is enough to compare

Comment: don't forget that your worst case scenario is `O(n^2)`, which means in this case `10^14`. can you imagine that number?

Comment: Each time you make the array 10x larger you have to allow 100x the amount of time. My guess is you didn't wait long enough.

Comment: you could easily add a System.out.println and print each time the number generated so you can see if it lags out somewhere or if it just needs a lot of time to process.

Answer (score 2):

> Anybody have any ideas of what the issue may be here?

When you make the array 10x larger you have to wait 100x longer as this is an O(n^2) algorithm.

> Is the executer having issues comprehending that many integers or what could the issue stem from?

No, the limit is 2^31-1 and you are a long way from the limit.

Running

```
interface A {
    static void main(String[] a) {
        for (int i = 25_000; i <= 10_000_000; i *= 2) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int[] arr = new int[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                arr[j] = r.nextInt();
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            insertion(arr);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.printf("Insertion sort of %,d elements took %.3f seconds%n",
                    i, time / 1e3);
        }
    }

    public static void insertion(int[] a) {
        int n = a.length;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            int j = i - 1;
            int temp = a[i];

            while (j > 0 && temp < a[j]) {
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
                j--;
            }
            a[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Insertion sort of 25,000 elements took 0.049 seconds
Insertion sort of 50,000 elements took 0.245 seconds
Insertion sort of 100,000 elements took 1.198 seconds
Insertion sort of 200,000 elements took 4.343 seconds
Insertion sort of 400,000 elements took 19.212 seconds
Insertion sort of 800,000 elements took 71.297 seconds
```

So my machine could take in the order of 4 hours, but it could take longer as a bigger data set doesn't fit in L3 cache, but rather main memory which is slower.